# How to call PHP function from Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to call specific php function on server and also to send some parameters.
Till now I achieved that I can open php file using HttpClient and executed data transfer to Json and show that in my app.
So, now I want to be able to call specific function and send parameter to it, how can I do that??
Sorry I didn't mansion that I need to call that function from Android.

here some code:

```
try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/posloviPodaci/index.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,   "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

            String line = "0";
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Parsing data
        JSONArray jArray;
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data = null;

            items = new String[jArray.length()];

            for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                items[i] = json_data.getString("naziv");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

Thanks in advance,
Wolf.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with an MVC framework, such as CakePHP, you can simply create a route to a function that will output whatever JSON you'd like.

Otherwise,
You can utilize something simple at the top of your index.php such as this:

```
<?php
   function foo($bar) { echo $bar; }
   if(isset($_GET['action']) && (strlen($_GET['action']) > 0)) {
      switch($_GET['action']) :
         case 'whatever':
            echo json_encode(array('some data'));
            break;
         case 'rah':
            foo(htmlentities($_GET['bar']));
            break;
      endswitch;
      exit; # stop execution.
   }
?>
```

This will let you call the url with a parameter of action.

http://10.0.2.2/posloviPodaci/index.php?action=whatever

http://10.0.2.2/posloviPodaci/index.php?action=rah&bar=test

If you need to pass more sensitive data, I recommend you stick with $_POST and utilize some form of encryption.

Comment: sorry I didn't put that I'm working Andriod app, and I want to call from there.

Answer (score -1):

You can  handle that on php side. Create a Json object with a field  called command and maybe a list of arguments.

On the php end after you decode the json just do:

```
if($obj.command == "foo"){
  foo($obj.arg[0],$obj.arg[1]);

}
```